# Optimising Laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

Picked up Laravel recently for an API project and have got it all set up and working, and Ive been migrating an API written from a php function with a concatenated SQL string into Laravel query builder, all is fine apart from one part.

I have a table of stock, and a features table, so I have defined a `hasMany` relationship on the model of stock to the features, and when I pass in a string array of features to the query I need to loop over each feature and then get back all the stock items that have those features.

Using a `whereIn` is not what I need as that will give me stock that has only one of the features. If I use a standard `where` that will give me 0 results as soon as multiple features are added.

I have achieved what I want with the following code, but its terribly slow to execute but I am unsure of a better way to get the same result:

```
foreach($value as $v){
    $builder->whereHas('features', function($query) use ($v) {
        $query->where('code', $v);
    );
}
```

Comment: I think in this case you need to define the reverse relationship between features and stock as well and then using eloquent you can fetch the related results.

Answer (score 1):

Use query builder instead of Eloquent to optimize queries...
For example:

```
DB::table('stock')->join('features',function($join){
   $join->on('features.id','=','stock.feature_id')
       ->where('code', $v);
})
->select('') <--- also select columns here..
->get();
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Comment: Thanks for this, How can I apply the result of that in a look back into a `Builder` object?

Comment: If it makes any difference I used this site (https://m.dotdev.co/writing-advanced-eloquent-search-query-filters-de8b6c2598db) to base my API on

Comment: You  receive a collection or std object but it's not the same than Eloquent's collection .. that difference is the cause of the performance

Comment: Yea I thought that would be the case, what is going to be my best approach here? the way its setup is very Eloquent and neat, but this change seems to throw it off