# Optimise Laravel Eloquent Query Result

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, query-optimization, laravel-query-builder

I have a homework table in **laravel-5.7** where 5000 records in the table also have some Relational records that are coming through **HasMany() or HasOne() Relation**. I tried many types of **Eloquent Queries**  to get fast results. but **Postman** result time becomes 10200ms to 10700ms but when i direct dispaly this into postman then i am getting this into 500ms to 1100ms. i want to get it in near about 800ms after binding form Laravel Resource or Normal Array.

problem is, when i try to show the Eloquent result direct then it coming around 600ms to 1000ms. but when i bind into an Array and display in postman then its taking 6200ms why? i do not know?

```
    $page = $req->page ?$req->page:1;  // set starting value for look query limit.
    $user = Auth::user()->student()->first();
    $studentProfile = Auth::user()->student()->first();

    // collecting all homework id that have assigned to student.
    $studentHWList =  StudentHomeWork::where("student_id",$studentProfile->id)
        ->select('home_work_id')
        ->get()->pluck('home_work_id');

   // collecting page by page of homework id.
    $hwLimitList =  Homework::where('session_code', dnc($req->require('sid')))
            ->whereIn('id',$studentHWList )
            ->where('approved', '1')
            ->select('id')
            ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
            ->get();
    $hwIndexes = $hwLimitList->pluck('id')->forPage($page,$this->recordLimit);

    $paginated = Homework::whereIn('id', $hwIndexes)
                        ->with( "user:id,username,name",
                                'subject:id,subject_name,subject_code',
                                'approveByUser','publishBy')
                        ->with(["likes"=>function($erw){
                                 $erw->select('id','home_work_id','complete_status','likes')
                                ->where("student_id", $studentProfile->id);
                        }])
                        ->with(['comment'=>function($qur){
                            $qur->where('parent_id',0)
                                ->where('user_id',$user->id);
                        }])
                        ->orderBy('id','desc')
                        ->get( );

    if( count($paginated))
    {
        $paginationData =  customPagination('getAllHW',$hwLimitList , $page , $this->recordLimit , $user, $studentProfile  );
        return response()->json(["error"=>0,"errmsg"=>"","paginationData"=>$paginationData  ,
            "response"=>['homework_list'=>$this->customResourceHWBinding($paginated , $req )],'auth'=>userType()]);

  

private function customResourceHWBinding($queryData , $request, $user, $studentProfile )
{
    $document_list =[]; $is_seen=0; $resultData =[];
  foreach ( $queryData as  $query )
  {
      if( count($query->document)  )
      {
          foreach($query->document as $document){
              if( $document->changed_filename )
              {
                  $file=""; $fileName ="";
                  $path =env('AWS_URL')."/uploads/".dnc($request->header('dbauth'))."/".$query->session_code."/homeWorks/";
                  if(is_s3FileExist( $path.$document->changed_filename ) )
                  {
                      $fileName =$document->changed_filename;
                 
                  }
                  $document_list[] = [
                      'oname'=> $document->changed_filename,
                      'ext'=>$fileName?explode('.', $document->changed_filename):"",
                      'url'=>$file,
                      'file_url'=>$document->changed_filename?$path.$document->changed_filename:""
                  ];
              }
          }
      }

      $resultData[] =   [
      'id'=>enc($query->id),
      'ids'=>$query->id,
      'pin_user_id'=>"",
      'pin_enabled'=>0,

      'created_by'=>$query->user->name,
      'created_by_image'=>getUserImage($query->user,$query->user->privilege,$request),
      'assignment_date'=>getDateFormat($query->assignment_date,0),
      'assigment_date_edit'=>"",
      'submission_date'=>getDateFormat($query->submission_date,1),
      'submission_date_edit'=>"",
      'class_code'=>$query->class_code,
      'subject'=>$query->subject?$query->subject->subject_name:"",   
      'topic'=>$query->topic,
      'is_student_seen'=> $this->studentHWSeen($query, $user, $studentProfile),
      'updated_at'=> date('d-m-Y H:i:s' , strtotime($query->updated_at)),
      'approved'=>$query->approved,
      'approve_by'=> '',
      'can_approve'=>0,
      'comment_count'=>0,
      'total_like'=>0,
      'documents_count'=>count($document_list)?count($document_list):0,
      'is_draft'=> $query->draft?$query->draft:0,
  ];
  }
  return $resultData;
}

private function studentHWSeen( $query , $user, $studentProfile)
{
    if(count($query->studentSeen))
    {
        foreach($query->studentSeen as $seen){
            if( user->privilege == 1  )
            {
                if($seen->student_id == $studentProfile->id )
                   return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I try to use **Resource** but it's also taking 3+seconds. I try too many others optimize a solution but not work in my case. someone told **Use query builder instead of Eloquent to optimize queries**. find here [Optimising Laravel query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462699/optimising-laravel-query) . is it a good answer for me? I am not sure. please help me.

please check my image.[image]

Eloquent Query Result
[image]

Comment: Well, if eloquent is fast, but displaying result for postman is delayed, then the problem will be in `customResourceHWBinding()`.  Try to find out which part of code is cousing problem. Maybe function `is_s3FileExist`, which have to connect to S3 and check of file exist.

Comment: Show us the generated SQL.

Comment: i check here. problem is here customResourceHWBinding i know.  is_s3FileExist removed but not getting anymore improvement.  there is any other way to bind all data into **Array or Laravel Resource** for representing for API.

Comment: I am looking for any technic that shows my result fast. because it is coming from database server in 500ms but resulting in API in 5 to 10 second....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to optimize this:

```php
$paginated = Homework::whereIn('id', $hwIndexes)
                        ->with( "user:id,username,name",'subject:id,subject_name,subject_code',
                            'approveByUser','publishBy')
                        ->with(["likes"=>function($erw){
                            $erw->select('id','home_work_id','complete_status','likes')
                                ->where("student_id",Auth::user()->student()->first()->id);
                        }])
                        ->with(['comment'=>function($qur){
                            $qur->where('parent_id',0)
                                ->where('user_id',Auth::id());
                        }])
                        ->orderBy('id','desc')
                        ->get( );
```

You run same code in nested query: `Auth::user()->student()->first()->id`.

Optimized version:

```php
$studentId = Auth::user()->student()->first()->id;


$paginated = Homework::whereIn('id', $hwIndexes)
                        ->with("user:id,username,name", 'subject:id,subject_name,subject_code', 'approveByUser', 'publishBy')
                        ->with(["likes"=>function($erw) use ($studentId) {
                            $erw->select('id','home_work_id','complete_status','likes')
                                ->where("student_id", $studentId);
                        }])
                        ->with(['comment'=>function($qur) {
                            $qur->where('parent_id',0)
                                ->where('user_id',Auth::id());
                        }])
                        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                        ->get();
```

Remember to add indexes to fields that you're using in where conditions.